# Why I can't click on an element in a ListView of AndroidStudio for selected it and use for showing other data in a new Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-listview

I have to select a row of a list which is a ListView of Android studio for take it and show in a new Activity the data of this object. But i can't
physically click on the row of the list so this are not selected and the action for view the new activity dont start. Please can someone help me? Thanks

```
this.listaCorrieri.setOnItemClickListener(Applicazione.getInstance().getControlloPrincipale().getAzioneSelezionaCorriere());

private class AzioneSelezionaPietanza implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ActivityPrincipale activityPrincipale = (ActivityPrincipale) Applicazione.getInstance().getCurrentActivity();
            List<Pietanza> listaPietanzeCategoria = (List<Pietanza>) Applicazione.getInstance().getModello().getBean(Costanti.LISTA_PIETANZE_PER_CATEGORIA);
            Pietanza pietanzaSelezionata = listaPietanzeCategoria.get(position);
            Applicazione.getInstance().getModello().putBean(Costanti.PIETANZA_SELEZIONATA, pietanzaSelezionata);
            Archivio archivio = (Archivio) Applicazione.getInstance().getModello().getBean(Costanti.ARCHIVIO);
            Pietanza pietanzaSimile = archivio.cercaPietanzaSimile(pietanzaSelezionata);
            activityPrincipale.mostraPietanzaSimile();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I just answered a similar question a couple of minutes ago. To get position of the item use: ```int i = yourListView.getAdapter().getItem(position);``` inside onItemClick

Comment: Thanks but this is for get the position of object selected in the list but I can't selected it because when I run the app I can't click on the row for select the object, the row dont respond at the click of the mouse